# WebForms page can't access properties defined in its own code-behind class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a WebForms page like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ReportsTo.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyApp.ReportsTo" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyApp" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyAppDBTools" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%
            Dim nextHigher As Integer? = UserLevelID
            ' do more stuff here
        %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
Imports MyAppDBTools

Public Class ReportsTo
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The ID of the user whose supervisor is being set.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Protected ReadOnly Property UserID As Integer
        Get
            Return CInt(Request("UserID"))
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The level of the user whose supervisor is being set.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Protected ReadOnly Property UserLevelID As Integer
        Get
            Return DBFunctions.GetUserLevelID(UserID, SessionHelper.ConnectionString)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

However I get compile errors when I reference the `UserID` and `UserLevelID` properties from the page:

> BC30451 'UserLevelID' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Why is this? Shouldn't I be able to access properties defined in the code-behind from the page? If not, where else can I put them? A singleton class?

Comment: Can you try to ````Inherits="ReportsTo"````

Comment: I think it should work but not sure about the `vb`. Would a `ToString()` help? See if this works first: `<%: UserLevelID %>`, or `<%: UserLevelID.ToString() %>`. You don't need to `dim` on the page, just use the property.

Comment: P.S. I can create a 'property' or code-behind variable with just, `protected readonly string test = "qwerty";`.

Comment: make it public or internal